# iOS 12 Errors: appears to be from a different NSManagedObjectModel than this context's

Tags: swift, core-data, ios12

I started to get the following error when launching my application on iOS 12 simulator. Did anybody face issue like this?

```
2018-08-11 21:17:44.440144+0300 CafeManager[4633:128874] [error] error: The fetch request's entity 0x600001f6e940 'TablesTable' appears to be from a different NSManagedObjectModel than this context's
```

I have global constant defined in AppDelegate:

```
let viewContext = AppDelegate.viewContext
```

And use it with NSFetchedResultsController for UITableView update, for example:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class HistoryTablesTableViewController: FetchedResultsTableViewController {
    //MARK: variables
    private var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<TablesTable>?
    private var currentTable: TablesTable?
    private var tableNameTextField: UITextField!

    //MARK: system functions for view
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sideMenu()
        addSyncObserver()
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        updateGUI()
    }

    // MARK: IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

    // MARK: side menu
    private func sideMenu() {
        if revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            revealViewController().rearViewRevealWidth = 260

            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
    }

    //MARK: functions for table update
    private func updateGUI () {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<TablesTable> = TablesTable.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "tableName", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.localizedStandardCompare(_:)))]
        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController<TablesTable>(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
        try? fetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! HistoryTablesTableViewCell
        if let tablesTable = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) {
            cell.tableNameLabel.text = tablesTable.tableName
            cell.cellDelegate = self
            cell.table = tablesTable
        }
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        currentTable = fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showTableSessions", sender: cell)
    }

    //MARK: prepare for segue
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showTableSessions" {
            if let tableSessionsTVC = segue.destination as? TableSessionsTableViewController {
                tableSessionsTVC.title = self.currentTable!.tableName!
                tableSessionsTVC.currentTable = self.currentTable!
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Delegates
extension HistoryTablesTableViewController: HistoryTablesTableViewCellDelegate {
    func didPressTablesCellButton(table: TablesTable) {
        currentTable = table
    }
}

// Common extension for fetchedResultsController
extension HistoryTablesTableViewController {
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sections?.count ?? 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
            return sections[section].numberOfObjects
        }
        else {
            return 0
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if let sections = fetchedResultsController?.sections, sections.count > 0 {
            return sections[section].name
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return fetchedResultsController?.sectionIndexTitles
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, at index: Int) -> Int {
        return fetchedResultsController?.section(forSectionIndexTitle: title, at: index) ?? 0
    }
}

// Observer to check that sync was performed to update GUI
extension HistoryTablesTableViewController {
    private func addSyncObserver () {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: Notification.Name(rawValue: appDelegate.syncDidFinishNotification), object: nil, queue: nil) {
            [weak self] notification in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.updateGUI()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the same time it looks like that app works, but had no chance to test everything properly yet.

I use CoreData, Seam3 framework.

I found the only one mention of this error on [github](https://github.com/superk589/DereGuide/issues/24), but do not see solution.

Comment: I'm now getting the same error.. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep looking.. Don't I know you from STV days?

Comment: @DavidDelMonte please post the answer here if you find the solution. As I checked, this error does not cause any real problems with my app, so I decided to focus on other things. I do not know what is STV, actually. Google shows me several companies with this name. Is it company name? :)

Comment: Same error here, did you found a solution?

Comment: @iGenio unfortunately nope.

Comment: are you still using this framework or it is not safe?

Comment: @iGenio I use it. As I have checked, these errors do not lead to any crashes or something like that. So in my case I decided to ignore it.

Comment: Having the same issue, I carefully investigated and made sure that any CoreData interaction is done on the main thread, but the error is still triggered when the FetchedResultsController performs its fetch. Since it only appeared when upgrading to iOS 12 and Xcode 10 I suspect that it is an issue of the Seam3 framework.

Answer (score 3):

I had been getting this error with iOS 12 also.  This is how I finally fixed it in my project. This is in Objective C, not Swift, but hopefully it will get you going in the right direction.

The code that produced this error looked like this

```
// in the init code for my object
NSString *pathm = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mycoredb" ofType:@"momd"];
NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathm];
self.model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];


// in another method in the object
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Model_name"];
[request setEntity:entity];
```

The issue has something to do with the entity.  So I updated my code to reflect the example on this page:  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FetchingObjects.html

Here is how my code looks now

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Model_name"];
```

no more "appears to be from a different NSManagedObjectModel than this context" error.

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was a simple solution, I am using 4 contexts and I had to set their parent to the main context.

```
var mainManagedContext: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}

lazy var backgroundQueueContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.parent = mainManagedContext
    return context
}()

lazy var mainQueueContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
    context.parent = mainManagedContext
    return context
}()

lazy var alternativeContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
    let context = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
    return context
}()
```

Comment: Brilliant. I've been looking for this solution for a while. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar when we created two instances of model even if they are read from the same `momd` file.  My assumption was that if it's read from the same file, they should be the same model, but I guess something has changed internally that no longer treats two instances from read from the same `momd` file as the same model.

Make sure when you're referencing `viewContext` it is as shared (same instance) of `NSManagedObjectContext` and not initializing a new model instance from the file.

I hope this helps.